# Tipos genéricos na chamada de método em Java

Tags: java, genéricos

Queria entender como isso funciona e o nome que dão para isso em Java.

Segue o trecho de código:

```
public <I, O> SimpleStepBuilder<I, O> chunk(int chunkSize) {
    return new SimpleStepBuilder<I, O>(this).chunk(chunkSize);
}
```

A dúvida é referente a esse primeiro `<I, O>`, fiquei confuso se isso seria o tipo de retorno, mas testando um pouco o tipo de retorno é `SimpleStepBuilder<I, O>`, o que me deixou confuso.

Código fonte: [spring-projects/spring-batch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/StepBuilder.java#L68)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O termo poderia ser parametrização genérica.

Isto é o momento que é definido quais serão os termos genéricos a serem usados na composição do método, é aí que os parâmetros genéricos estão sendo definidos (não confundir com parâmetros do método em si). Lembre-se que a genericidade é só uma forma de parametrizar algo, então tem algo que funciona como super variáveis no código que será trocado pelo valor (um tipo) no momento da chamada. Esta parte define o que será usado.

De fato você está correto que o tipo do retorno já é o `SimpleStepBuilder<I, O>` que usa o `I` e `O` para generalizar o tipo que será efetivamente usado na chamada do método (instanciando essa classe `SimpleStepBuilder` parametrizando dois tipos nela. Esta parte consume a definição criada antes.

Em geral fica mais fácil para o compilador saber antes a definição, mas é menos intuitivo para ler porque no consumo o argumento genérico estará em outro lugar.

Em C# seria mais intuitivo:

```
public SimpleStepBuilder<I, O> chunk<I, O>(int chunkSize) => new SimpleStepBuilder<I, O>(this).chunk(chunkSize);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/SyntaxReturn.cs).

Answer (score 4):

Como dito na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/414133/77268) anterior, o termo poderia ser parametrização genérica.

O `<I, O>` na assinatura significa que o método pode lidar com esses dois tipos genéricos, isso não é o retorno. Por exemplo, você poderia ter um método sem retorno e com essa assinatura.

```
 public static <I, O> void test(I i, O o){
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

No seu caso, o retorno do método é o `SimpleStepBuilder<I, O>`

Comment: Esse termo é para outra coisa.

Comment: Não há um termo fácil e bem definido sobre isso, mas eu coloquei na minha resposta o que é, esse que você colocou tem a ver com o assunto, mas é para algo bem mais sofisticado que isso, esse código não tem restrição (*bounded*).